# The value of argocd-secret is further encoded to base64

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, kustomize, argocd

When managing secrets in argocd, I encode the value in argocd-secret with base64 and set it to manifest.

In that case, although I use kusotomize, build and apply it, secret encoded by base64 will be encoded to base64 further.

```
$ echo -n "clientid" | base64
Y2xpZW50aWQ=

$ echo -n "clientsecret" | base64
Y2xpZW50c2VjcmV0
```

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: argocd-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  dex.github.clientID: Y2xpZW50aWQ=
  dex.github.clientSecret: Y2xpZW50c2VjcmV0
```

If you use kustomize build to build and check the difference, it looks like this

```
$ kustomize build --load_restrictor none overlays/dev/ap-northeast-1/argocd | k diff -f -

+  dex.github.clientID: WTJ4cFpXNTBhV1E9
+  dex.github.clientSecret: WTJ4cFpXNTBjMlZqY21WMA==
```

I don't understand why something encoded by base64 is encoded further.
I'm going to ask for someone's help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your case and it looks like it isn't further encoded by **kustomize** but by **kubectl** (either by `kubectl` client itself or by `kube-apiserver` performing the operation requested by e.g. `kubectl apply` command).

And [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-manually) you can find a fragment that sheds some light on why this is actually happening:

> The Secret contains two maps: `data` and `stringData`. The `data` field is
>   used to store arbitrary data, encoded using base64. The `stringData`
>   field is provided for convenience, and allows you to provide secret
>   data as unencoded strings.

The `data` field serves for storing the data already encoded using base64 and value of this field isn't further encoded when we apply the `Secret`. The `stringData` however behaves quite differently. It *allows you to provide secret data as unencoded strings* and for that reason it is further encoded when you run `kubectl apply`. In your example you use `stringData` field and although it contains already encoded data, it is treated as any other string and in consequence is encoded again.

**Solution:** simply use `data` rather than `stringData` map in your `Secret` and your base64 encoded strings won't be encoded again during the resource creation.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually secret controller who encodes the string. So, you can't pass an encoded string into a yaml. You need to leave it in plain text:

```
$ echo -n demo | base64
ZGVtbw==
$ echo -n ZGVtbw== | base64
WkdWdGJ3PT0=

$ kubectl create secret generic demo --from-literal=key=demo
secret/demo created
$ kubectl create secret generic demo2 --from-literal=key=ZGVtbw==
secret/demo2 created

$ kubectl get secret demo demo2 -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  data:
    key: ZGVtbw==        <- word demo got encoded
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2020-06-04T13:41:27Z"
    name: demo
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "10118413"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/demo
    uid: bc39444c-e4f6-43ba-b151-705e15811831
  type: Opaque

- apiVersion: v1
  data:
    key: WkdWdGJ3PT0=    <- encoded string of demo got encoded further
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: "2020-06-04T13:41:47Z"
    name: demo2
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "10118469"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/demo2
    uid: 2fe63343-06b4-4f47-94cd-9fe8e12fb388
  type: Opaque
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

Note: this was not always like that. And it can actually change again. Back in the days, you had to encode it, then you must not, then again...